# Trigger an event when the event count maximum of last 12 months window

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I have a requirement like, Trigger an event when the idle well count maximum of last 12 months window.

For Example:

### Well_date                  Count

1986-01-01 00:00:00 17 
1986-02-01 00:00:00 16 
1986-03-01 00:00:00 23 
1986-04-01 00:00:00 33 
1986-05-01 00:00:00 31 
1986-06-01 00:00:00 42 
1986-07-01 00:00:00 43 
1986-08-01 00:00:00 43 
1986-09-01 00:00:00 41 
1986-10-01 00:00:00 42 
1986-11-01 00:00:00 46 
1986-12-01 00:00:00 52

Output: 
1986-12-01 00:00:00 52

Suppose, if the event count is minimum of last 11 months then it will be ignored.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This one will give you a stream of last max well counts, i.e. the max excluding the current event:

```
insert into LastMaxStream select rstream max(well_count) as lastMax from SomeEvent
```

The LastMaxStream can be used to compare:

```
@name('out') select * from SomeEvent(well_count > (select lastMax from LastMaxStream.std:lastevent()));
```

There may be other solutions but that is the one that comes to mind. For considering some time period add that to the group-by clause, or declare a context that starts when 1986 starts and ends when 1986 ends, for example.

Comment: I tried with some other solution to find the maximum value using below query.  but this query is not returning any values.  **Query: ** SELECT countyName, eventDate.minus(11 month) AS fromDate, eventDate as toDate, max(wellCount) as wellCount from GeneratedCountyEvent 
WHERE eventDate.between(eventDate.minus(12 month), eventDate, true, false).